# Solve $f(x) = \lambda\int_0^\pi(x+y)f(y)\mathrm dy$

Tags: integral-equations

Solve the integral equation
$$
f(x) = \lambda\int_0^\pi(x+y)f(y)\mathrm dy
$$

with $f(x)$ integrable in [0,π].

From my comment below: ...I think that a non trivial solution is $f(x)=Ax+B$
with $A$ and $B$ constant, but i can't check it.

(see the comments for others attempts)

Thanks

Comment: Are you assuming anything else about function $f$?

Comment: Integrable in $[0,\pi]$.I think that a non trivial solution is $f(x)=Ax+B$ with $A$ and $B$ constant, but i can't check it....

Comment: Alex: I get the system $A=\lambda\left[\frac{A\pi^2}{2}+B\pi\right], \; B=\lambda\left[\frac{a\pi^3}{3}+\frac{B\pi^2}{2}\right]$. That looks like an invertible system to me. [EDIT] Yeah, thanks copper.hat. Also, Wolfram Dev Platform yields only the trivial solution. So, back to square one.

Comment: @AdrianKeister: You have a small typo., $a \to A$.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Yes i get the same system. I tried to solve it and I found something like $ B_i = c_i(\lambda_i)*A_i$ with $\lambda_1=\frac{(4\sqrt(3)-6)}{\pi^2}$ and $\lambda_2=-\frac{(4\sqrt(3)+6)}{\pi^2}$ and $c(\lambda_i)$ a rational function, but when I substituted this solution in the equation I get an incorrect result, perhaps due to calculation errors I do not know....

Comment: Wolfram Dev Platform doesn't help much - the DSolveValue command doesn't yield a non-trivial solution.

Comment: @Alex: the system is invertible and homogeneous, which means it has only the trivial solution.

Comment: @AdrianKeister but is it invertible for all $\lambda$? The determinant is always non zero? For example for $\lambda=\frac{4\sqrt(3)-6}{\pi^2}$ the solution seems to be $B= \frac{\pi(2-\sqrt(3))A}{2\sqrt(3)-3}$. But you're probably right and I made mistakes! Sorry and thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see what you are about. Yes, $\lambda=\frac{-6\pm 4\sqrt{3}}{\pi^2}$ will give you non-trivial solutions for $A$ and $B$. I haven't worked out what $A$ and $B$ are. Lemma type this all up into a solution for you, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is clear that $f(x)=0$ is a trivial solution to this integral equation. However, in separating out the original IE like this:
$$f(x)=x\left(\lambda \int_0^{\pi}f(y) \, dy\right)+\lambda\int_0^{\pi}y \, f(y) \, dy,$$
the ansatz $f(x)=Ax+B$ suggests itself. Plugging this into the equation yields the equation
$$Ax+B=x\lambda\left[\frac{A\pi^2}{2}+B\pi\right] + \lambda\left[\frac{A\pi^3}{3}+\frac{B\pi^2}{2}\right].$$
Setting the coefficients of like powers of $x$ equal yields the (mostly) invertible (and definitely) homogeneous system of equations:
$$A=\lambda\left[\frac{A\pi^2}{2}+B\pi\right]$$
$$B=\lambda\left[\frac{A\pi^3}{3}+\frac{B\pi^2}{2}\right].$$
For most values of $\lambda$, the system is invertible, which implies the trivial solution. (So we see that the trivial solution is a special case of our ansatz, though we could have seen that from the get-go.) However, if we cast this into standard $\mathbf{A}x=0$ matrix form, we can take the determinant of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and set it equal to zero to find if there are non-trivial solutions. We obtain the equivalent system
$$0=A\left[\frac{\lambda\pi^2}{2}-1\right]+B\lambda\pi$$
$$0=A\,\frac{\lambda\pi^3}{3}+B\left[\frac{\lambda\pi^2}{2}-1\right].$$
Taking the determinant yields the quadratic
$$\frac{\lambda^2\pi^4}{12}+\lambda\pi^2-1=0,$$
with solutions
$$\lambda=\frac{-6\pm 4\sqrt{3}}{\pi^2}.$$
We can plug this into one of the relationships between $A$ and $B$ to get a parametrized family of solutions. We obtain
$$B=\frac{A\,(-2\pm\sqrt{3}\,)\,\pi}{3\pm 2\sqrt{3}}.$$
The final solution, therefore, to the integral equation is
$$f(x)=tx+\frac{t\,(-2\pm\sqrt{3}\,)\,\pi}{3\pm 2\sqrt{3}},$$
where $t$ is a parameter.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. OTOH, it's better not to answer a question that shows no effort whatsoever.

Comment: Well, he did put forth a significant effort in the comments.

Comment: Then, he should have included such effort in the body of his question. It's not a good practice to give further clarification in comments because not everyone read them.